# Partial Mock Test fails on call in Private Method that was called from Mocked method call

Tags: rhino-mocks, partial-mocks

Below, I have code for an object that I would like to test. 
I am using a partial mock in my test and want to mock out the call to InsertData when I am testing the GenerateReport method.
For some reason, my test continues down through InsertData to DoSomeStuff and fails on the Path.Combine line. What am I missing?

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private readonly IMyClassDataProvider _myClassDataProvider;

    public virtual string WorkingDirectory { get; set; }

    public MyClass(IMyClassDataProvider myClassDataProvider)
    {
        _myClassDataProvider = myClassDataProvider;
    }

    internal virtual void ValidateWorkingDirectory()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(WorkingDirectory))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Must set Working Directory before any method calls.");
        }
    }

    public virtual void GenerateReport(vars)
    {
        ValidateWorkingDirectory();
        InsertData(_myClassDataProvider.GetData(vars), "ReportName"); 
                    //want to mock the call above
    }

    internal virtual void InsertData(DataSet analysis, string fileName)
    {
        DoSomeStuff();
    }

    private static void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        string fileName = FileNameProvider.Get();
        Path.Combine(WorkingDirectory, fileName); //fails here!
    }
}


[TestFixture]
public class MyClassTests : TestFixtureBase
{
    private MockRepository _mocks;
    private IMyClassDataProvider  _myClassDataProvider;
    private MyClass _myClass;
    private var _vars;

    [SetUp]
    protected void Init()
    {
        _mocks = new MockRepository();
        _myClassDataProvider = _mocks.StrictMock<IMyClassDataProvider >();
        _myClass = _mocks.PartialMock<MyClass>(_myClassDataProvider);
        _vars = "who cares";
    }

    [Test]
    public virtual void ShouldGenerateReport()
    {
        DataSet dataSetToReturn = new DataSet();
        using (_mocks.Ordered())
        {
            Expect.Call(() => _myClass.ValidateWorkingDirectory());
            Expect.Call(_myClassDataProvider.GetData(vars)).Return(dataSetToReturn);
            Expect.Call(() => _myClass.InsertData(dataSetToReturn, "ReportName"));
        }
        _mocks.ReplayAll();
        _myClass.GenerateReport(vars);
        _mocks.VerifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I update the line to:
    Expect.Call(() => _myClass.InsertData(dataSetToReturn, "ReportName")).IgnoreArguments();
The problem goes away. Can someone explain that as well?

Answer (score 1):

Changing InsertData from internal to public will fix this. I'm assuming a method needs to be public for Rhino mocks to be able to mock out the method call.

Concerning adding IgnoreArguements after the expectation, I'm not too sure how this passed because it still called the orignal method when I tried running this code.

Hope this helps